# Signed payload is not valid when using signxml but xmlsec one is valid

Tags: xml, xml-signature, zeep, xmlsec

Could you help me to find out why the two libraries (signxml and xmlsec) do not sign the same.
The signature accepted by the server is xmlsec.

Code sign [signxml](https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml):

```
signer = XMLSigner(
    method=methods.enveloped,
    signature_algorithm="rsa-sha1",
    digest_algorithm='sha1',
    c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315')
ns = {}
ns[None] = signer.namespaces['ds']
signer.namespaces = ns

signed_root = signer.sign(xml_element, key=self.chave, cert=self.certificado, reference_uri=None)
```

But the signed payload is not correct, ending up with either signature verification failed error/getting error message to check for the signature. When I used the xmlsec, it is generating in a proper way. But I have to use signxml as it does not have platform dependencies. Attached both the xml output files here.

https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml/files/6207744/signs.zip

And the payload here [payload.txt](https://github.com/XML-Security/signxml/files/9668342/payload.txt)

I see the Issuer details tag is missing in signxml generated output document and there are two Reference URI and digest method and value in xmlsec generated output but seeing only one on the signxml. How can I make the signxml to generate and verify the signature and able to successfully make SOA API invocation?

XMLSec code: Ref https://github.com/orcasgit/py-wsse/blob/ff4fea90687606af31d4b31cbdb3e753154299a4/wsse/signing.py#L19

```
wsse = signing.sign(envelope=envelope, keyfile=key_path, certfile=cert_path)
signing.verify(envelope=wsse.decode(), certfile=cert_path)
```

I would appreciate any help on this from anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I'm able to generate the XML signature that is being verified by `signxml.XMLVerifier()` using this. Earlier could not verify the signature generated but this did the trick `lxml.etree.tostring(signed_root)` Thanks for the awesome post: https://technotes.shemyak.com/posts/xml-signatures-with-python-elementtree/. Payload with signature able to get the response from the remote server as well.

```
import lxml
import signxml
from xml.etree import ElementTree

key = open("key.pem").read()
cert = open("cert.pem").read()

root = ElementTree.fromstring(payload, parser=lxml.etree.XMLParser())

signed_root = signxml.XMLSigner(method=signxml.methods.enveloped).sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
data_serialized = lxml.etree.tostring(signed_root)

# Now able to verify this
signxml.XMLVerifier().verify(data_serialized, x509_cert=cert)

#To get the signed XML
print(data_serialized.decode())
```